# How come a JSX element accepts a method with parenthesis vs without it as its child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How come when I try to pass in a method without parenthesis, into a React component as a child of one of the JSX elements, I get an error in the console, but as soon as I add parenthesis, it's all fine and dandy?

For ex:

```
randomFunction(){
//do something here
}
```

This gives me an error:
`<div>{this.randomFunction}</div>`

But this doesn't.
`<div>{this.randomFunction()}</div>`

What adds to my confusion is because of the way methods are called when used as a prop. We don't use the parenthesis then.

Answer (score 3):

`this.randomFunction` returns the function itself

`this.randomFunction()` actually calls (executes) the function

A function is not a valid JSX element, but the return from an executed function is.

So if:

```
function randomFunction() {
  return <div><div>
}
```

And you call:

```
<div>{this.randomFunction()}<div>
```

The function will succeed

Comment: Ah ok, but when we pass a function down to a child component as a prop, since it's just being called as a JSX element attribute, parenthesis can be ignored right?

Comment: When you pass a function to a component as a prop, you are passing the function, which can then be executed within the component. It's not a matter of parenthesis 'can' be ignored it's about your use case.

i.e. 

myFunction={this.randomFunction}

then within ur component

call myFunction()